# Any guidance to create this sharp bevel effect?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, illustration

[image]

I am experienced with the Creative suite but I think there's several ways to achieve this. A part of me thinks that this is a 3D model with added render effects/extra processing to make it look ever so slightly bitmapped if you can see but otherwise, any manual guidance would be very very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This doesn't look like a 3D model, but a simple *Bevel & Emboss* filter.

In Photoshop, make a dark gray text or shape. I managed to manipulate the image you posted to get the original shape. It's a bit ragged along the edges, which will affect the result, but it will do.

[image]

In the *Layers* panel, select the layer with the shape, click the *fx* button in the bottom of the panel and select *Bevel & Emboss*.

I used the following settings:

[image]

(You need to adjust *Size* to fit your image.)

I got the following result, which I think is pretty close:

[image]

Your image in the same crop for comparison:

[image]

Comment: you a G!!!!!!!! Thank you!<3